# como eliminar un elemento de una lista que esta en otra lista python

Tags: python

hola gente recurro a esto por que intente de todo y no he podido solucionar esto, bueno el problema que tengo es que tengo una lista y en esa lista hay otra lista y lo que quiero hacer es reemplazar un elemento de esa lista mediante un input nose si es posible hacer eso.
soy novatito en python se agradecería todo ayuda.

ejemplo de la lista

lista = [[2,3,4,5,6]]

por ejemplo quiero reemplazar el elemento 4 mediante teclado.

esta es una parte del codigo.

```
import titulo, fechasjunta, lugar, nombre, descripcion


lista_recordatorio = []


while True:
    print("""
    Ingrese opcion
    
    1- Agregar recordatorio
    2- Modificar recordatorio
    3- Eliminar recordatorio
    4- Mostrar recordatorios
    5- Salir
    """)
    try:
        opcion = int(input("> "))

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- OPCION 1

        if opcion == 1:
            list = []
            titulo.agregarTitulo()
            fechasjunta.agregarFecha()
            lugar.agregarLugar()
            nombre.agregarNombre()
            descripcion.agregarDescripcion()



            list.append(titulo.titulos)
            list.append(fechasjunta.fechita)
            list.append(lugar.lugare)
            list.append(nombre.nombre)
            list.append(descripcion.descripcioncita)

            lista_recordatorio.append(list)

            print("\nRecordatorio\n")
            for i in lista_recordatorio:
                print()
                for a in i:
                    print(a)
            print("-----------------------------------------")

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- OPCION 2                 

        elif opcion == 2:
            print("""
            Selecione una opcion a modificar
            
            1- Titulo
            2- Fecha
            3- Lugar
            4- Nombre
            5- Descripcion
            
            """)

            opcion = int(input("> "))

            if opcion == 1:
                pass

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- OPCION 3

        elif opcion == 3:
            print("Eliminar recordatorio")
            print("0 para eliminara el primer recordatorio 1 para el segundo y asi sucesivamente\n")
            for i in lista_recordatorio:
                print(i)
            

            del lista_recordatorio[int(input("Ingrese el indice a eliminar: "))]
            print("-----------------------------------------")


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- OPCION 4          

        elif opcion == 5:
            print("Hasta pronto")
            break        

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- OPCION 5

        elif opcion == 4:
            print("Recordatorios")
            for i in lista_recordatorio:
                print(i)
            print("-----------------------------------------")


    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error de tipo: {e}")
```

Comment: o sea, lo que quieres hacer es que, ingresando un numero y posición, se cambie ese numero automáticamente ¿no?

Comment: @Mr.Barbo claro quiero reemplazar ese elemento  que esta dentro de una lista que a la vez esta en otra lista nose si me explico

Comment: sería bueno que mostraras qué has intentado exactamente. En general, iría bien leer [ask] y dar un [mcve]

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' ahí esta el código lo que pasa es que lo que había intentado lo borre y por eso recurrí acá, lo que necesitaba solo era una parte del enunciado para un próximo post subiré lo que intento.

Comment: uy, aquí hay mucho código :) Mejor mostrar una parte mínima y representativa y también cómo ejecutas, qué te da y qué querrías que te diera, etc. Insisto en recomendar [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

imaginemos que tuvieras una lista con 5 elementos como `lista = [1,2,3,4,5]`, podrías acceder a los elementos de esa lista usando: `lista[i]` donde `i`
es la posición donde esta el elemento, y como, a diferencia de las tuplas, las listas son mutables, puedes cambiar ese elemento haciendo `lista[i] = x` donde x es lo que quieras.
si ademas tienes una lista dentro de otra(como en tu ejemplo), puedes acceder a ella usando `lista[i][j]` donde `i` y `j` son las "coordenadas" del elemento y también puedes cambiarlo usando `lista[i][j] = x`.

un ejemplo de programa seria este:

```py
lista = [[2,3,4,5,6]]

dato = input("ingrese un dato: ")
coord_a = int(input("ingrese las coordenadas a del dato: "))
coord_b = int(input("ingrese las coordenadas b del dato: "))

lista[coord_a][coord_b] = dato
print(lista)
```

Comment: Hola, @Salvador. Si la respuesta es válida no olvides marcarla. Saludos.